# PostgreSQL task: trigger to calculate average

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, database-trigger

I need help with the following problem.

Let two tables and relation between them:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    val REAL
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    val REAL
);

CREATE TABLE A_B (
    a_id INT NOT NULL,
    b_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I need to set B (val) so that it is always average of all A (val) if and only if relation between them exists in A_B. How to use trigger for it? Thanks and sorry for grammar.

Comment: If data in table b getting a bit stale is okay, I would suggest a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a view to expose this derived information. Actually storing it makes little sense, and maintaining integrity will be tedious.

```
create view view_b as
select b.id, avg(a.val) val
from b
left join a_b ab on ab.b_id = v.id
left join a on a.id = ab.a.id
group by b.id
```